# How to get all values from a column in a function parameter (when creating it)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am creating a report that uses the `max()` function. But, instead, I would like to create another function called **max_pos** where I can add a parameter that gives the order of the maximum value. In case:

```
max_pos(value, 2) //same effect as max but it gets second max value.
```

So I came across a problem. When I'm going to `create the function`, how do I get all the values of a column in a single parameter? And how do I return only one line? Take the example:

```
+-----+--------+
| id  | values |
+-----+--------+
|   1 | value1 |
|   2 | value2 |
|   3 | value3 |
+-----+--------+
```

Said in other words: i'm going to get value1, value2 and value 3 in `create or replace function` ... with only one parameter and return only one row (as max function does)?

I hope it was clear.

Comment: Given that `nth_value()` already exists, there doesn't seem to be much use for such a function.

Comment: The second value of a max function, how would it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gordon Linoff suggested, it might make more sense to use the built-in [`NTH_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/NTH_VALUE.html#GUID-F8A0E88C-67E5-4AA6-9515-95D03A7F9EA0) function.

It's an analytic function and the syntax is a bit tricky.  Here's an example:

```
select
    distinct nth_value(value, 2)
        over (order by value rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) second_max
from mytable1;
```